# Find integers $u$ and $v$ satisfying $20u+63v=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Find integers $u$ and $v$ satisfying $20u+63v=1$.

I tried to use the Euclidean Algorithm 
$63=20.3+3$,
$20=3.6+2$,
$3=2.1+1$
Then we have $1=3-2.$
Now what should be the coefficients?

Comment: Your second equation should be $20 = 6 \cdot 3 + 2$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it.

\begin{array}{r|rrr}
    a &  b &  c &   d \\
\hline
      & 63 &  1 &   0 \\
   -3 & 20 &  0 &   1 \\
\hline
   -7 &  3 &  1 &  -3 \\
      & -1 & -7 &  22 \\
\hline
     &   1 &  7 & -22
\end{array}

Note that, in each row, $b = 63c + 20d$.
The "next" row is computed by multiplying the "current" $(b,c,d)$ by $a$ and adding the result to the previous $(b,c,d)$.

Hence $1 = 63(7) + 20(-22)$

Answer (score 3):

A (not really) alternative approach. We construct the continued fraction of $\frac{63}{20}$:

$$ \frac{63}{20}=\left[3;\frac{20}{3}\right]=\left[3;6,\frac{3}{2}\right]=\left[3;6,1,2\right]\tag{1} $$
then we truncate it and we expand it back:
$$ [3;6,1] = [3;7] = \frac{22}{7}. \tag{2} $$
By the properties of continued fractions, $\frac{63}{20}-\frac{22}{7}$ is a number of the form $\pm\frac{1}{7\cdot 20}$. Indeed
$$ 63\cdot 7 - 20\cdot 22 = 1 \tag{3} $$
and we have found a solution of the original problem, hence all of them:
$$ u=-22+63k,\quad v=7-63k.\tag{4} $$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find the coefficients.

As you observed, the Euclidean algorithm yields
\begin{align*}
63 & = 3 \cdot 20 + 3\\
20 & = 6 \cdot 3 + 2\\
3 & = 1 \cdot 2 + 1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1 + 0 
\end{align*}
Working backwards, we obtain
\begin{align*}
1 & = 3 - 2\\
  & = 3 - (20 - 6 \cdot 3)\\
  & = 7 \cdot 3 - 20\\
  & = 7(63 - 3 \cdot 20) - 20\\
  & = 7 \cdot 63 - 22 \cdot 20
\end{align*}
so a particular solution of the equation $20u + 63v = 1$ is $u = -22$ and $v = 7$.  The general solution of a linear Diophantine equation $ax + by = c$ with particular solution $x_0, y_0$ is 
\begin{align*}
x & = x_0 + \frac{b}{d}t\\
y & = y_0 - \frac{a}{d}t
\end{align*}
where $d = \gcd(a, b)$ and $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Here $a = 20$, $b = 63$, $d = \gcd(20, 63) = 1$, $u_0 = -22$, and $v_0 = 7$, so we obtain the general solution
\begin{align*}
u & = -22 + 63t\\
v & = 7 - 20t
\end{align*}
where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, as you can verify by direct calculation.